# Stored procedure for getting value from one table which are no inserted in other table?

Tags: java, sql-server

I have a table named `platform_Users` and other table `Assigned_Users`.

I want MSSQL sp "`getAllUnAssignedUSER`" which get all users records from `platform_user` which are not inserted in `Assigned_User`..

Comment: what have you implemented so far?

Comment: i have one table in which all users basic information are stored,when any user assigned a role then dat userid with roleID and other information are stored in Assigned_Users table..so i want sp which collect records from Users which are not inserted in Assigned_Users Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE    
    PROCEDURE `getAllUnAssignedUSER`() 

    BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM platform_Users pu WHERE pu.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM Assigned_Users);
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

left join the tables together

Then in the where clause return where Assigned_Users.UserID is null

Should return all records from 1st table where they have no joined entry in the assigned table

Comment: add code to describe what you want. It will help the for an understandable answer .